# Magento 2 css edit

Tags: magento2, css, less-css

I start building new theme from scratch and I add `custom.css` to 
`mytheme->magento_theme->web->css`

when i test new css with simple code website not working correctly

I already:

Add css to `default.head.blocks.xml`

Deploy static content

Comment: can you please share your coed in questions?

Comment: You can import your custom css into theme's _extends.less and deploy and check

Comment: Check with private browser to see changes... Because it doesn't make cache.... Else delete your custom css in pub/static/yourtheme to check your changes

Comment: working with me by add _extends.less to customer moduel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **default_head_block.xl** file in your custom theme in **Magento_Theme** directory.

Add your custom css file to **app/design/frontend/namespace/theme/web/css/custom.css**

> app/design/frontend/namespace/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

and copy this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <css src="css/custom.css" />
        </head>
    </page>
```

After adding this, delete your **pub/static/frontend/** directory and deploy static files.

Answer (score 0):

The file that you are using needs to be `default_head_blocks.xml`, not `default.head.blocks.xml`. This file can live in a lot of places, but i prefer to have it here:

> app/design/frontend/{{your_namespace}}/{{your_theme}}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

Make sure the css file is should up in the `pub/static/frontend` folder structure. The css might be in different places inside those fodlers depending on your set up, so i can say the exact path. But it needs to be in there for the browser to see it. This is easy to check as the browser will give you a 404 on the file if the xml is set up correctly.

Double check the syntax of your file. It should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <!-- <link src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" src_type="url" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
        <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

And inside that file, you need to make sure that your xml is valid, i can't count how many times i missed a closing tag that made the file invalid. Test it here:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp